# Bootstrap table search does not work when loaded into CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system

Hello and thank you in advance for your help.

When I load this fantastic searchable table `[http://codepen.io/adobewordpress/pen/gbewLV][1]` into my cms it does not work..

Again, thank so much for your help

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to publicly imply US Government does not afford proper coders? Or that they hired the wrong person for the job, for that matter? Or that they are asking for free coding services? Not sure which one is worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs the .search class here: `$(".search").keyup(function ()`. You have not that class in the input search box.

Your input text should be like:

```
<input type="text" class="search">
```